# How to rearrange the user registration form fields

Tags: users

I want to **Rearrange** and **Rename** the default fields with added fields on user registration form in drupal7 site, I could rearrange only the fields which is added by me but i want to rearrange combining both the default and added one. can anyone help on this.!

Comment: Is your requirement is to rearrange the order of fields in user registration form (Home » Administration » People) ..??

Comment: @Abin: yes, i tried to rearrange the field here admin->config->people->account settings->manage fields, but i could not able to see the default fields

Comment: check [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/962476)

Answer (score 4):

Fields can be rearrange by changing `'#weight'` attribute of field in `hook_form_alter()`. You will have to create a custom module and have to alter the form and its element. The associative array would be something like this

```
$form['account']['name']['#weight'] = 7;
```

Comment: where can i find this is it modules->user->user.module file?where can i find?

Answer (score 4):

Implement `hook_form_user_register_form_alter()`. You can rearrange the `$form` array that is passed to this hook by adjusting the [weights](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#weightval) and [titles](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#title).

Answer (score 1):

The easy way, without any editing of configuration files is to just change the order of the fields in /admin/config/people/accounts/fields

Clear your caches and it's done.